# Templating in react: how to combine markup and logic

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm relatively new with react and react native, and am currently struggling with how to correctly to create my components, specifically on where I should add logic that defines my markup. To give an example, I've create a functional component called `ActivityExecutionsComponent`, in its body an array is created that is named `datesArray`. For each value of in `datesArray` I want to output a `<HabitDayComponent />`. The following code basically achieves this:

```
export function ActivityExecutionsComponent() {

// Some code that creates datesArray

return (
  <View style={style.chips}>
    {datesArray.map((date) => (
      <HabitDayComponent day={date} />
    ))}
  </View>
);
}
```

I now, however, want to change markup. Whenever my `datesArray` has more than 7 `habitDayComponents`, I want to group them so each group is wrapped with a `<View>` object. I'm a bit uncertain if I should all this logic in the return statement? How do you usually tackle logic like this in a react app?

```
export function ActivityExecutionsComponent() {

// Some code that creates datesArray

return (

    {datesArray.map((date, index) => (
      // Some logic with a modulus operator to calculate the groups
       <View style={style.chips}>
       <HabitDayComponent day={date} />
       </View>
    ))}
  
);
}
```

So basically I'm unsure if  I should calculate logic like this in a helper function of the body of `ActivityExecutionsComponent`, of if I should try to add it all in the return statement.

Comment: i think it's absolutely no problem to do it in render. but this is a question of design.

Comment: React Native has built-in component to render list, both grouped and ungrouped. https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist and https://reactnative.dev/docs/sectionList

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the logic using a function as well as in the return statement. Both will work fine. But to keep the code clean and less cluttered it's a good practice to use some functions instead of adding code directly in the return statement. So that return statement does not get complex as the app grows.

You can also implement your logic like this:

```
export default function ActivityExecutionsComponent(){

  let list = [];// array which contains a list of components

  datesArray.map((dates, index)=>{
  // add component in the array using push function
  list.push(
     // Some logic with a modulus operator to calculate the groups
     <View style={style.chips}>
       <HabitDayComponent day={date} />
     </View>
   )});

  return (
    <View>
      {list}// array showing a list of components
    <View>
  )    
}
```